# What's the differences between a UINT and a WORD with Profinet

Tags: types, cpu-word, plc, uint, structured-text

I'm developing a project on a Siemens PLC and i'm wondering if I should use a Word or a UINT to store a 16-bit value. Is there any differences between the two?

Comment: According to my brief googling, in this case, there is no difference between a `WORD` and a `UINT` on a Siemens PLC, they are both unsigned 16-bit data types. Generally, `INT` datatypes are as long as whatever the CPU can handle, so they could technically change. A `WORD` will always be 16 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally there is no real difference between the two.  The only time where it really matters is when the input type to a function block is either a `WORD` or `UINT`.  Then it will matter.

Generally speaking, if you are choosing between a `UINT` or a `WORD` to store a numerical value the typical best practice is go ahead an use an `UINT`.  If you are looking to store a hex value you would want to use the `WORD`.

Comment: In other words: UINT conceptually represents a single number, while a WORD conceptually represents a collection of raw bits.

Answer (score 0):

Technically and theoretically there is no difference between `WORD` and `UINT` but `UINT` stores unsigned 16 bit values and `WORD` stores Hexadecimal Value